# How can my app fully occupy the entire window after hiding the Navigation Bar & the Status Bar?

Tags: c#, android, mvvmcross

I need my app to fully occupy the entire window after hiding the Navigation Bar & the Status Bar.

Below is my code where I hide the Status and Navigation Bar.

```
this.Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = Android.Views.StatusBarVisibility.Hidden;
this.Window.SetFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen, WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen);
this.Window.DecorView.SetFitsSystemWindows(true);
```

Albeit the navigation buttons are gone, the app still does not occupy the whole window. I'm pretty sure I am missing a step or I might be using the SetFitsSystemWindows method incorrectly.

If anybody can help out or at least point me in a direction where I can resolve this is much appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you trying to archieve its the immersive full-screen mode, in this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html) you could read more about this feature.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I've taken a look at the link and it seems that this was introduced in API 19. My app's min Sdk is 14 but I don't see any problem moving that to 19. I still have to figure out how to do this in code for mvvmcross. I've seen a couple of native Java examples but I have to hunt down equivalent methods, properties ,etc...

Comment: I hope you can archieve it :)